# Scroll to top with router.navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I am trying to scroll to the top of my application on route change. I have enabled `{scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'}` which works for all `routerLink`s but the issue I am having is, when using a `router.navigate` inside the component the scroll position is persisted when I don't want it to, I need the page to be at the top on load.

I have tried

`this.router.navigate(['./url',someData]).then(() => window.scrollTo({ top: 0}));`

and

`this.router.navigate(['./url','someData'], {state: { scrollTop: 0 }});`

but both are still persisting the scroll position.

Comment: You may try `scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'`

Comment: top and enabled have both been tried, anyhow they only work for routerLinks not the router.navigate

Comment: `{scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'}` is used to restore the scroll position of the page when navigating _back_, so it has nothing to do with any of these. When you call `this.router.navigate(...)`, do you navigate to a different url? or the same url?

I think your best bet is to create a StackBlitz and share it with us.

Comment: @skouch2022 it is a different url, in this case, the first page is a log in screen, and the redirect is the 2FA code entry. I will try to make a stackblitz

Comment: Cool, we'll wait for your StackBlitz.